# `rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:references` creates user_id_id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I have two models: User and Post. 
In order to make an association between them I type this into the console:

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:references
```

This creates migration:

```
def change
  add_reference :posts, :user_id, foreign_key: true
end
```

However, when I look into the database, it shows that I created 'user_id_id' column and not 'user_id' which I expected. What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def change
  add_reference :posts, :user, foreign_key: true
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you specify references option just provide model name

```
rails generate migration add_user_to_posts user:references
```